# Не получается установить библиотеку: "module 'plistlib' has no attribute 'readPlist'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.9

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\павел\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Павел\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rj9otkyu\\pyobjc-framework-quartz_cb24c58eeace4f4e8e468a9eb3d8cf99\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Павел\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rj9otkyu\\pyobjc-framework-quartz_cb24c58eeace4f4e8e468a9eb3d8cf99\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2064mkyj'
         cwd: C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rj9otkyu\pyobjc-framework-quartz_cb24c58eeace4f4e8e468a9eb3d8cf99\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rj9otkyu\pyobjc-framework-quartz_cb24c58eeace4f4e8e468a9eb3d8cf99\setup.py", line 60, in <module>
        Extension('Quartz.CoreVideo._CVPixelBuffer',
      File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rj9otkyu\pyobjc-framework-quartz_cb24c58eeace4f4e8e468a9eb3d8cf99\pyobjc_setup.py", line 389, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rj9otkyu\pyobjc-framework-quartz_cb24c58eeace4f4e8e468a9eb3d8cf99\pyobjc_setup.py", line 203, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist('/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist')
    AttributeError: module 'plistlib' has no attribute 'readPlist'
```

Comment: А как называется библиотека? Добавьте в вопрос ее название, [edit]

Comment: pyobjc-framework-quartz

Answer (score 0):

Причина ошибки в том, что [библиотека](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/) для `macOS`, а у вас `windows`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все ясно

Comment: @Mercurial77, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)